# How to add GtkWidget to GtkToolbar?

Tags: c, gtk

I want to insert GtkEntry widget to GtkToolbar. Following line

```
gtk_toolbar_insert(GTK_TOOLBAR(searchPanel_Toolbar),
                      GTK_TOOL_ITEM(searchPanel_Entry), -1);
```

gives me this error:

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_toolbar_insert: assertion `GTK_IS_TOOL_ITEM (item)' failed
```

How can I add widgets to GtkToolbar without `gtk_toolbar_insert_widget()` which is deprecated?

Comment: The error means that `searchPanel_Entry` is not a `GtkToolItem`. What exactly is `searchPanel_Entry` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GtkToolbar *toolbar = gtk_toolbar_new();
GtkToolItem *item  = gtk_tool_item_new();
GtkEntry *entry = gtk_entry_new();

gtk_container_add( GTK_CONTAINER(item), GTK_WIDGET(entry) );
gtk_toolbar_insert( GTK_TOOLBAR(toolbar), GTK_TOOL_ITEM(item), -1 );
```